# Why does the Managed Identity Policy fail with "AutomatedFlow" value?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to set up a continuous data export from Azure Data Explorer to SQLDB.
I have created an external table, and my managed identity can insert data into the table.
The documentation says I need to add the "AutomatedFlow" value to the Managed Identity Policy.

I use the following code as snipped from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-managed-identity-policy-command) (of course with correct identity and db).

````
.alter database db policy managed_identity ```
[
  {
    "ObjectId": "d99c9846-1615-a2f9-a96f-78e136ba93eb",
    "AllowedUsages": "NativeIngestion, ExternalTable"
  }
]
````

This code runs. I add "AutomatedFlow" to the list and it fails. I tried adding "All" instead as this allegedly enables all rights - this code runs but I get a "the managed identity used for automated flow, is not authorized to access the databases under the given query. Please assign the correct roles and try again."
Does anyone know if I do something wrong, or if this is a known bug?

Comment: Your managed identity should be authorized to run a query on an ADX database and insert the results into a SQL table.
It seems it lacks a viewer role on the ADX database.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz: Running into a similar issue here - does this mean when using the cluster's system managed identity that the cluster has to be given permissions to access itself?

Comment: Let me take another look

Comment: This actually solved the problem at hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the cluster system managed identity doesn't automatically have rights to access the data. So assigning the `Viewer` role to the cluster identity for the relevant database (or `AllDatabaseViewer` on the cluster) solves this particular problem. This should also work for user managed identities.